# List posts with same tag?

Tags: url-rewriting, tags

Is there any way to list my posts by tags ?

i need to alter the URL too...

like **mysite.com/tags/mytag** will list all the posts having '**mytag**' as tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Posts By Tag plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-by-tag/).

Answer (score 0):

You could use this snippet in your theme.

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------
// List Posts by Tag
//-------------------------------------------------------------

// Grab 5 posts by default

function list_posts_by_tag( $tag, $show=5 ) {

     global $post;

     $posts = query_posts('tag=' . $tag . '&showposts=' . $show );

     ?>

     <ul class="tagged-list">

          <?php foreach ($posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>

               <li class="tagged-item"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

          <?php endforeach;

          //Reset Query
          wp_reset_query();

          ?>

     </ul>

     <?php }
```

(from [groupmindmedia.com](http://groupmindmedia.com/tutorials/list-wordpress-posts-by-tag-2/))

You'd need to add that code to functions.php, and then add a call to the function in your theme:

```
list_posts_by_tag( "cats", 5 );
```